# How to define a function as an operation on the other option

Tags: function-construction

I would like to define the function g as the Laplacian of the function f as follows:

```
ClearAll[f, g]

f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2

g[x_, y_, z_] := \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y, x}\), \(2\)]\((f[x, y, z])\)\)
```

However, it doesn't calculate g[1, 1, 1] for me.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove : from the definition of g

Comment: You list of variables is `{x, y, x}` in the Laplacian instead of `{x, y, z}`. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: In addition to the variable list issue, and to expand on @chris comment: here you want your function definition to use an *immediate* assignment (`=`) rather than a delayed one (`:=`). The laplacian should be calculated once and for all at definition, before substituting numerical values for the variables. If you wait until the variables have numerical values, the derivative operation will fail. In your case, this is masked by the nature of $f$ whose laplacian is constant. See e.g. [these questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Define+function+as+derivative).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2

g[f_] := Laplacian[f, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]
```

Let us check:

```
g[f[x, y, z] ]

(*  6  *)
```

Edit: To address the comment of @MarkoB I admit that did not really understand the task. Please see the  version returning the value in a given point:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y^3 + z^3

g[x1_, y1_, z1_] := 
 Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"] /. {x -> x1,y -> y1,z -> z1};
```

Let us check:

```
g[1, 1, 1] 

(*  18  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This happens to work here here to the nature of the function ask, but it doesn't solve the problem of substituting numerical values for the variables.